# Is it possible to convert a pull-chain lamp to a "turn-knob"?

Tags: switch, lamp, socket

I have a pull-chain lamp that is in need of repair (the pull-chain doesn't always turn the lamp on)

Would I able to swap this out with a turn-knob?

I have seen some youtube videos, but they all mostly describe replacing the socket/switch with the same type.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

A photo would help.

If you mean the pull-chain switch is part of the socket, then yes, you can easily replace that with a socket that has a twist switch.

If the switch is mounted separately, then it's probably still easy to do but would require more disassembly/reassembly.